# Prompt theme with Git support marking a number after a questionmark

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, powerline

I'm using Ubuntu on WSL2, having installed powerlevel10k on oh-my-zsh.

[image]

What is that weird question-mark-number next to the git branch name, what does it mean?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have 1 untracked file in your repo. Do `git status --short` and [you'll see the same symbol](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_short_format). See the [P10k documentation](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k) for an overview of the symbols it uses.

---

As an aside, be aware that most of the other symbols used by P10k are different from the ones used by `git status` (or other prompts; see below). As you can see, it uses a lot of Unicode symbols, whereas `git status` restricts itself to ASCII symbols.

Further adding to the confusion, the [`git-prompt.sh` theme](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh#L38) distributed with `git` uses yet an another set of symbols, based on those . These, too, are restricted to ASCII symbols. Since they are not officially documented anywhere, I’ll list them here, in case anyone needs it:

| Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `<` | behind |
| `>` | ahead |
| `<>` | diverged |
| `=` | in sync |
| `|` | operation in progress |
| `+` | staged |
| `*` | unstaged |
| `%` | untracked |
| `$` | stash |
| `?` | sparse checkout |

In any case, when in doubt about any particular prompt theme, always check to see if there’s documentation.